# Zpanel - Mail Configuration

Tags: email, smtp, imap

I am trying to configure emails within my zpanel portal and I am running into problems accessing email from external clients like Thunderbird or Android Email. I set up the Mailbox and it works perfectly to send/receive emails if I use roundcube but how do I configure my VPS or ZPanel to allow to send/receive email from external clients?

I've heard something to do about MX Records. I have not idea how to configure those. I've also heard about opening ports but don't know which ones I need to open or if I have to install additional things.

Looking forward to your reply!

Comment: Please ask on server fault, stack overflow is for /programming/ questions.